# Which browsers allow me to switch languages without reinstalling?

Tags: firefox, browser, multilingual, language

I would like to use the fact the browsers can be installed in various languages as a way to practice my French. So if I am in Firefox and see the word "options" in the menu and want to know how it is translated in the French version, I would like to click a button to switch the browser language to French quickly and then use the French version until I don't understand one of the French words, then switch back to English, etc.

**Are there any browsers which allow me to switch languages dynamically in this way without reinstalling?**

## Addendum

The quick-locale-switcher that freethinker suggested seems to switch the language of the add-on but not the language of the browser, or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: You're not going to learn much French from browser menus.

Comment: I produce online software training videos and want to be able to do this in French as well, so it is precisely all of these little translations of "options", "tools" and "settings" that I would like to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried myself, but I guess downloading and running a French Firefox from PortableApps would work: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable/localization.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go, I can't run both the English and French portableapp versions at the same time, but can start one and stop the other.

Comment: I installed firefox sync and so am now able to quickly switch between the French and English versions simply by closing one and opening the other, and all my bookmarks etc. remain, very nice.

Comment: Another solution is to allow Firefox Portable to run multiple instances (http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/run-multiple-versions-portable-firefox-parallel/, at the end of the article). I tried and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following firefox addon to change your locale in firefox without restarting.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher/

Comment: I installed that but it seems to only change the language of the add-on, not the browser (see above).

Comment: and if you restart after that, has the browser language changed?

Comment: you have to restart it to change the language of the addon but the language of the browser stays the same, the switcher seems to be for spelling, etc.

Comment: some more info here http://www.myfirefox.co.uk/tips--tricks/change-menu-language